# killSignal option in JSON config file with Forever module [node.js]

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, arguments, forever

I'm using Forever with nodeJS and I want to use a config file (a JSON file) to start my server. I also want to use option `--killSignal=SIGTERM` , but i want it in the JSON file instead of using the CLI. Is that possible? I tried (according with [Forever Documentation](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) )with:

```
{ 
    "uid": "app",
    "append": true,
    "watch": false,
    "script": "app.js",
    "sourceDir": "/home/user/test/",
    "args": [" --killSignal=SIGTERM "],
    "logFile": "/home/user/test/log/foreverlog.log",
    "outFile": "/home/user/test/log/foreverlogOut.log",
    "errFile": "/home/user/test/log/foreverlogErr.log"
}
```

but the `"args"` line does not work. I also tried putting it as last line in the JSON file, or even putting

`"script" : " --killSignal=SIGTERM app.js"`

and

`"sourceDir": "--killSignal=SIGTERM /home/user/test/"`

but none of these works.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I used a workaround. 
I created a config file and a start.sh file; the .sh file simply contains

```
forever start --killSignal=SIGTERM ./config/foreverconfig.json
```

I also created a stop.sh file which simply contains

```
forever stop app.js
```

This works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax for args is meant to be something like this;

```
"args": ["--killSignal", "SIGTERM"]
```

However, in this case I think you're looking for;

```
"killSignal": "SIGTERM"
```